# Add enchantments with Integer.valueOf?

Tags: bukkit

I'd like to add an enchantment to an item in a yml file, however, I'm not quite sure how to do this. I'm trying something along the following lines:

```
ItemStack kit = new ItemStack(Integer.valueOf(singleItems[0]), Integer.valueOf(singleItems[1]));
ItemMeta kitMeta = kit.getItemMeta();
kitMeta.addEnchant(Integer.valueOf(itemEnchants[0]), Integer.valueOf(itemEnchants[1]), false);
kit.setItemMeta(kitMeta);
p.getInventory().addItem(kit);
```

That's just giving me an Eclipse error, but I'm guessing there is a way of doing it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it's an Eclipse error. The types are incompatible.

Comment: The method addEnchant(Enchantment, int, boolean) in the type ItemMeta is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, Integer, boolean). Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addEnchant` method in the `ItemMeta` class takes an `Enchantment` enumerator, not an `int` for the enchantment type, in addition to the other arguments which you're using correctly as far as I can tell. I assume the integer you get from `itemEnchants[0]` is the enchantment ID. You can use the deprecated `Enchantment.getById(int id)` method to get the corresponding `Enchantment` enumerator for each ID.